# Dvd upscaling with out quality loss to MKV

Tags: dvd, matroska, vob

I have a DVD containing a VOB of resolution `720×640`, with DTS audio.

I would like to upscale a the video to `1920×816` while retaining DTS audio without lose of video quality, and save it as an MKV file. How can I achieve this??

Comment: To get a more targeted answer it may be beneficial for you to mention your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/). HandBrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a selection of modern, widely supported codecs which relies on FFmpeg.

You can upscale the video using the "Size" options under "Picture Settings"..

That said, you should be aware that while upscaling, every pixel in the video will be (almost) doubled or stretched and the resulting video will look like it's of a higher resolution. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't look any different from a full screen option in any normal video player. (See [this](https://superuser.com/a/290155/432540) really informative answer by [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) to learn more.)

Comment: Thank you for ur prompt reply.I tried to install handbrake  software on my laptop.but it failed.it required .net file fron windows.i downloaded it and then installed it.It again blocked my installatation. Any another method for it